# Get products from a specific seller from Amazon via API

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

I need to:

1. Get my products from my market (filter the products by sellerId/merchantId, hipotetically) on Amazon by API.
2. Render the products in my webpage outside Amazon.
3. Use Amazon FPS to allow user to purchase my product.

Point #3 is quite clear for me. But #1 which seems the simplest I really don't know how to do. I also tried **Amazon MarketPlace Webservice** and **Amazon Product Advertising API** but without success.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until recently, you could use the Product Advertising API to look up products from a given merchant. Now, you need to use the [Amazon Marketplace Web Service](https://developer.amazonservices.com/index.html/177-7971310-0935865) and programmatically request a report for all your listings (using the "GetReportRequestList" operation with the report type "_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_"). See the [Report API Reference (in PDF)](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/bde/MWSReportsApiReference._V399870835_.pdf) for details.

Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer ... do you have any working example of the code...

Comment: Is it possible to use the old veraion od Product Advertising API instead of the MWS?